# HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Good day,

In my java web application, I am trying to create a `restTemplate` call which go through a proxy first before go for the destination, and I am using Spring 3.0.4.

Base on this article, https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/394270/im-using-an-apache-httpclient-to-make-an-outbound/ , I need to use `HttpClientBuilder`. So my code will be as follow:

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
httpClientBuilder.setRoutePlanner( getProxyRoutePlanner() );
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.useSystemProperties( ).build( );
```

Until this step, I need a `RequestFactory` to hold this `httpClient`. However, in my Spring 3.0.4, I only have 3 `RequestFactory`, which is `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`, `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, and `CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and `ClientHttpRequestFactory` no have constructor to hold `httpClient`.
`CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory` has, but its using old version of `httpClient`, which is `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`, which is not same with `CloseableHttpClient` in my above code.

Would like to seek advice on how to pass the `httpClient` in RequestFactory in Spring 3.0.4. Or there are another way to do it.

Comment: You cannot. As Spring 3 only supports older versions of the HttpClient library. Either upgrade Spring or use an older version of the HttpClient library.

Comment: @M.Deinum , possible or any way to cast the `CloseableHttpClient` to older version of `HttpClient` library?